# Selection across pages in EXT JS 3.x

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

We are using EXT-JS 3.x. To select records from pages, used the method selectRecords(). Now, I can select records when I navigate the pages. But the problem is, on clicking the submit button all the selected records across pages should be visible. But below line of code    `grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections()`
returns the selected records in the current page.
Whether there are any options available to get all the selected records?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if It can be great for you, but I can suggest you to use a new column in the store to indicate if the row is selected or not. This column will be a boolean. You can set it value with listeners rowselect and rowdeselect. 
On submit you will be able to query the store to get only the records with the correct indicator value.

For example:

> ```
> var myStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({ 
>         fields: [{name:"col1", type:"string"}, {name:"INDICATOR", type:"'boolean'"}]
>     });   
> var myGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
>     store: store,
>     columns: [...//Don't put the INDICATOR here
>     sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect: false}),
>        ....
>        listeners: {
>          rowselect: (e,index, record){
>               record.data["INDICATOR"] = true;
>          },
>          rowdeselect: (e,index, record){
>               record.data["INDICATOR"] = false;
>          },
>          ....
>     }
> });
> ```

On submit

> ```
> var mySelection = myStore.query("INDICATOR", true);
> ```

I hope I give you a great example and it's not to complicated. 
I haven't test my code so maybe you will have to correct it a little bit.

Good luck!

Comment: On every row select and deselect, i have added selected records in object. Instead of retrieving selections from    grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections() , i have retrieved selected record from my object.